# How to HIDE/SHOW CUSTOM Title On button click In Android

Tags: android, titlebar

I am working on an android project. And I want to show / hide the custom title bar on  Button click. This button is for media player (full screen size / custom screen size ) please help me.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        ctx=this;
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title1);
    //  FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    //  FrameLayout frameLayout2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu1);
```

for hide custom title i am using using following code `onClick()`

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is will hide the action bar:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

this will make him back:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

Comment: thank your for this response. I have tried this code but found an error    07-03 10:57:56.519: E/AndroidRuntime(1101): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content